# How to return value from the bottom of recursive stack

Tags: python, recursion

I try to figure out how to return value from the bottom of the recursive stack.

```
def removeNthFromEnd(self, head: Optional[ListNode], n: int) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    kth = -1
    def helper(curr, prev, length):
        if not curr:
            return length - n

        length += 1
        kth = helper(curr.next, curr, length)

        if length == kth:
            prev.next = curr.next

    dummy = head
    helper(head, None, 1)
    return dummy
```

The first stack unwind set the `kth` value, next will be `None`. I can't figure out how to pass it forward to the top.

I understand why it works in that way, only seek for resolution. Not explanation.

Comment: Although you can write a function inside your function, there's really no reason to do that here.

Comment: How would `dummy` ever change here? This is the same as `return head`.

Comment: You probably want `return helper(head, None, 1)`

Comment: @tadman it is true, a bit of smell. but it doesn't matter in the scope of the question.

Comment: You probably want `return kth` at the end of `helper`, and `return helper(head, None, 1)` at the end of `removeNthFromEnd`.

Comment: It does matter here because it complicates understanding of whatever's going on here. Remember: Recursion is just another way of using a *stack* to solve a problem.

Comment: to pass it forward to the top you need to use `return`

Comment: [remove nth node from end of list](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-nth-node-from-end-of-list/description/) if anyone want to see full problem statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more memory efficient solutions, but if you want to do it this way, then:

1. There is no `return` statement that is executed except in the base case, this means that a caller will get `None` from the recursive call, except for one time.
2. There is no need to pass more than the second argument to `helper`, i.e. `prev`. `curr` can be derived from it, and the `length` parameter is not needed: you can `return n` in the base case, and *decrease* that value as you backtrack.
3. The idea of a dummy is nice, but then the idea is that it is a *new* node that *precedes* `head` in the extended linked list. Making only a synonym for `head` brings you nothing useful.

Here is your code with those three issues fixed:

```
class Solution:
    def removeNthFromEnd(self, head: Optional[ListNode], n: int) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        def helper(prev):
            if not prev.next:
                return n

            i = helper(prev.next) - 1

            if i == 0:
                prev.next = prev.next.next
            return i

        dummy = ListNode(0, head)
        helper(dummy)
        return dummy.next
```

Comment: took a closer look. i love it a lot. very nice and clean. thanks a lot again for the answer.